# How to automatically capitalize field on form submission in Django?

Tags: python, django, sorting, django-models, django-forms

I have a `ProductForm` where users can add a `Product` to the database with information like `title`, `price`, and `condition`.

How do I make it so that when the user submits the form, the first letter of the `title` field is automatically capitalized?

For example, if a user types "excellent mattress" in the form, django saves it as "Excellent mattress" to the database.

Just for reference, the reason I ask is because when I display all the product objects on a page, Django's sort feature by title is case-sensitive. As such, "Bravo", "awful", "Amazing" would be sorted as "Amazing", "Bravo", "awful" when as users, we know that is not alphabetical.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could [override the Model's `save` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods) (which has the benefit of being able to concisely handle numerous fields in one place):

```
class Product(models.Model):
    ...
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for field_name in ['title', 'price', ... ]:
            val = getattr(self, field_name, False)
            if val:
                setattr(self, field_name, val.capitalize())
        super(Product, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Just for clarification / sake of learning, will this save method override the default save method such as I would have to write the "remaining components" of the save method? I.E. if I use this save method to specify that it should capitalize the 'title' field on save, do I have to write anything else to  make sure the Product Object saves properly?

Comment: Nope, the line `super(Product, self).save(*args, *kwargs)` takes care of that (it calls the parent's save method - in other words, performs the save as usual having carried out your custom code)

Comment: what exactly is *args and *kwargs? Do I need to specify those arguments? I've left them blank at the moment and it seems to be working...

Comment: They are positional arguments and keyword arguments: http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python/

Comment: Dangerous typo: it's `(*args, **kwargs)`, not `(*args, *kwargs)`. There's a difference! Fixed.

Comment: Great solution.  FYI, if you want to capitalize the entire word and not just the first letter, use .upper() instead of .capitalize().

Answer (score 26):

Forms have a built-in hook for cleaning specific fields ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute)), which would be a cleaner (pun intended) location for this code:

```
class ProductForm(forms.Form):
    ...
    def clean_title(self):
        return self.cleaned_data['title'].capitalize()
```

Far less code than the accepted answer, and no unnecessary overrides.

Comment: I would also prefere the forms clean method(s) above overriding the save method. Isn't that what the clean methods are for ?

Comment: Not if you need to capitalize 10 fields in your model for example. Overriding the save method allows you to easily perform the capitalization on numerous fields at once, as was specified in the original question. That said, I agree that in the case of a single field, using the `clean_` method is quicker

Comment: isn't it meant to return the original `self.cleaned_data['title']`? "This method should return the cleaned value obtained from cleaned_data, regardless of whether it changed anything or not." (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/validation/#using-validators)

Answer (score 2):

Use Python's [`capitalize()` function](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.capitalize).

## edit:

see [Jeremy Lewis' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11996963/how-to-automatically-capitalize-field-on-form-submission-in-django/12001244#12001244) on where to use this function.

:)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ensure your data is consistent, I'm not sure that capitalizing at the form / view level is the best way to go.

What happens when you add a Product through the admin where you're not using that form / save method? If you forget the capital, you're in for data inconsistency.

You could instead use your model's save method, or even use the pre_save signal that django sends.

This way, data is always treated the same, regardless of where it came from.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [clean method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects) in models, ie:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    ...
    def clean(self):
        self.title = self.title.capitalize()
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need all first letters of all words to capitalize use `val.title()` in Jeremy Lewis' answer. If you use `val.capitalize()` then "hello world" would be "Hello world", with `title()` you can get "Hello World"